# Replacing a form from woothemes-sensei with my own custom form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, action, hook-woocommerce

In this image: [image]

it shows what i want to achieve, a total replacement of a piece of html that was built from a php page.

This is the code that creates the form and button in the green square (**functions.php**):

```
function insert_custom_form_start (){

//echo '
    ?>
                        <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="sensei_reg_username" placeholder="<?php _e( "gebruikersnaam", "woothemes-sensei" ); ?>" id="sensei_reg_username" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST["sensei_reg_username"] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST["sensei_reg_username"] ); ?>" />
                        </p>

                        <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                            <input type="email" class="input-text" name="sensei_reg_email" placeholder="<?php _e( "Email adres", "woothemes-sensei" ); ?>" id="sensei_reg_email" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST["sensei_reg_email"] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST["sensei_reg_email"] ); ?>" />
                        </p>

                        <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="sensei_reg_password" placeholder="<?php _e( "wachtwoord", "woothemes-sensei" ); ?>" id="sensei_reg_password" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST["sensei_reg_password"] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST["sensei_reg_password"] ); ?>" />
                        </p>

                        <!-- Spam Trap -->
                        <div style="left:-999em; position:absolute;"><label for="trap"><?php _e( "Anti-spam", "woothemes-sensei" ); ?></label><input type="text" name="email_2" id="trap" tabindex="-1" /></div>
<?php
                        //';

}

function insert_custom_form_end (){
    echo'</div> <!-- end #main -->';
    echo'</div> <!-- end #primary -->';
}
add_action('register_form','insert_custom_form_start', 10);
add_action('sensei_register_form_end','insert_custom_form_end', 10);
```

And in this piece i tried to remove the old form so now only the new form shows (**functions.php**):

```
add_action('sensei_register_form_start','removeOldRegisterForm', 10);
function removeOldRegisterForm(){
    echo '<h3>remove old register form and button</h3>';

    remove_action( 'sensei_after_main_content','sensei_register_form_start', 10 );
    remove_action( 'sensei_after_main_content','sensei_register_form_end', 10 );

    //remove_option( 'users_can_register'); //removes all forms instead of just the first one
}
```

Unfortunately i cant seem to get the remove action to work, maybe i dont fully understand how the adding and removal of hooks works.

People already suggested i make a seperate login page and then redirect it to the 'my courses' page (which wont show the login/register forms IF the user is logged in). But i think that is a bit redundant, i just want to replace it with a better looking form and not make the site less efficient with all sorts of workarounds.

Let me know if i should provide extra information!

ps: the code from 'class-sensei-frontend.php' im trying to fiddle with is as follows:

```
if ( get_option('users_can_register') ) {

                // get current url
                $action_url = get_permalink();

                ?>

                <div class="col-2">
                    <h2><?php _e( 'Register', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?></h2>

                    <form method="post" class="register"  action="<?php echo esc_url( $action_url ); ?>" >

                        <?php do_action( 'sensei_register_form_start' ); ?>

                        <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                            <label for="sensei_reg_username"><?php _e( 'Username', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="sensei_reg_username" id="sensei_reg_username" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['sensei_reg_username'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['sensei_reg_username'] ); ?>" />
                        </p>

                        <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                            <label for="sensei_reg_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <input type="email" class="input-text" name="sensei_reg_email" id="sensei_reg_email" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['sensei_reg_email'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['sensei_reg_email'] ); ?>" />
                        </p>

                        <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                            <label for="sensei_reg_password"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="sensei_reg_password" id="sensei_reg_password" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['sensei_reg_password'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['sensei_reg_password'] ); ?>" />
                        </p>

                        <!-- Spam Trap -->
                        <div style="left:-999em; position:absolute;"><label for="trap"><?php _e( 'Anti-spam', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?></label><input type="text" name="email_2" id="trap" tabindex="-1" /></div>

                        <?php do_action( 'sensei_register_form_fields' ); ?>
                        <?php do_action( 'register_form' ); ?>

                        <p class="form-row">
                            <input type="submit" class="button" name="register" value="<?php _e( 'Register', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?>" />
                        </p>

                        <?php do_action( 'sensei_register_form_end' ); ?>

                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The login form function:

```
     public function sensei_login_form() {
                ?>
                <div id="my-courses">
                    <?php Sensei()->notices->mayb

e_print_notices(); ?>
                <div class="col2-set" id="customer_login">

                    <div class="col-1">
                        <?php
                        // output the actual form markup
                        Sensei_Templates::get_template( 'user/login-form.php');
                        ?>
                    </div>

                <?php
                if ( get_option('users_can_register') ) {

                    // get current url
                    $action_url = get_permalink();

                    ?>

                    <div class="col-2">
                        <h2><?php _e( 'Register', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?></h2>

                        <form method="post" class="register"  action="<?php echo esc_url( $action_url ); ?>" >

                            <?php do_action( 'sensei_register_form_start' ); ?>

                            <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                                <label for="sensei_reg_username"><?php _e( 'Username', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="sensei_reg_username" id="sensei_reg_username" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['sensei_reg_username'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['sensei_reg_username'] ); ?>" />
                            </p>

                            <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                                <label for="sensei_reg_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                <input type="email" class="input-text" name="sensei_reg_email" id="sensei_reg_email" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['sensei_reg_email'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['sensei_reg_email'] ); ?>" />
                            </p>

                            <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                                <label for="sensei_reg_password"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                <input type="password" class="input-text" name="sensei_reg_password" id="sensei_reg_password" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['sensei_reg_password'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['sensei_reg_password'] ); ?>" />
                            </p>

                            <!-- Spam Trap -->
                            <div style="left:-999em; position:absolute;"><label for="trap"><?php _e( 'Anti-spam', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?></label><input type="text" name="email_2" id="trap" tabindex="-1" /></div>

                            <?php do_action( 'sensei_register_form_fields' ); ?>
                            <?php do_action( 'register_form' ); ?>

                            <p class="form-row">
                                <input type="submit" class="button" name="register" value="<?php _e( 'Register', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?>" />
                            </p>

                            <?php do_action( 'sensei_register_form_end' ); ?>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete change in how you should do this now that I see more of the code and what you want to accomplish. There might be a hook for you to use (I know Woocommerce well but not Sensei), but the alternative (or only/best) way to do this is to create a folder in your theme named `sensei`, inside that create a folder named `user`, and then inside that put a file named `login-form.php`. So your theme directory would look like this:

```
functions.php
sensei/
 user/
  login-form.php
style.css
```

In `login-form.php`, put whatever form code you want. This will override the default Sensei template located in `wp-content/plugins/sensei/templates/user/login-form.php`. Technically, you should copy that `login-form.php` file into your theme's `sensei/user/login-form.php` file and then replace the form code. That way, you maintain all the other hooks in that file.

Notice that the plugin structure has `sensei/templates/user/login-form.php` but your structure should **not** include the templates folder.

Sidenote: This same method works for all of the other files in the plugin's templates folder. In fact, that's exactly what it's there for - so you can fully customize it using a combination of hooks, filters, and the raw template files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i currently have this and it shows the h3 and the custom form but also still the default form (which was supposed to be removed). 

`add_action('init','removeOldRegisterForm', 10);
function removeOldRegisterForm(){
    echo '<h3>remove old register form and button</h3>';
  
  
 remove_action( 'register_form','insert_custom_form_start');
 remove_action( 'sensei_register_form_end','insert_custom_form_end');
 
 
 add_action('register_form','insert_custom_form_start');`

Maybe another plugin or something from storefront is interfering?

Comment: i'll add the entire function code as a new block, function sensei_login_form()

Comment: You shouldn't wrap it in the "init" hook because the Sensei function isn't hooked in yet so it can't remove what hasn't been hooked. Your remove_action should just be in your functions.php, not inside any other hook. Make sense?

Comment: i already tried it outside of the init hook (just in functions.php) but still doesnt work